# Angular RxJs : how to handle Outputs events priority based on firing order

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

In my Angular App , I have a widget which has two events outputs.
This widget comes from a 3rd party library and I can't change its behaviour.

```
<myWidget
  (onAlwaysEvent)="onAlwaysEvent($event)"
  (onSometimesEvent)="onSometimesEvent($event)">
</myWidegt>
```

When both are fired: those two events are fired almost at same time, but with this order:

**1-** *`onAlwaysEvent`*

**2-** *`onSometimesEvent`*

***My situation is this :***

- *When both are fired:*
  I need to set *`onSometimesEvent`* **as priority** and **cancel** the first one `(onAlwaysEvent)`
- And when '`onAlwaysEvent`' is the only fired:
  Evidently it's normal

(I have no cases where`onAlwaysEvent` is not fired)

Ideas to set `onSometimesEvent` as priority, just when fired **?**

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: I don'r understand what this means *I need to set onSometimesEvent as priority and cancel the first one (onAlwaysEvent)*. You want to ignore an immediate emission from `onAlwaysEvent`?

Comment: @martin maybe ; let onAlwaysEvent wait to onSomestimesEvent firing , if it siot fired , so i do its job , else it gives the hand to onSomestimesEvent

Answer (score 0):

You could call one event for both cases, then check within the function if it was "always" or "sometimes", by adding a boolean as parameter.

```
<myWidget
  (onAnyEvent)="onAnyEvent($event, $sometimes)">
</myWidget>

<sometimes-button onclick="onAnyEvent(e, true)" />
<always-button onclick="onAnyEvent(e, false)" />
```

Then check in the function if the boolean was set:

```
onAnyEvent(event, sometimes) {
    if (sometimes) {
        // only do sometimes code
    } else {
        // only do always code
    }

    // do code for both
}
```

Comment: the widget comes from a 3rd oart library , i can't change its behaviour (buutons ) , morover , the to events are called according to different inputs , i can't change it to only one event , as it's not mine , i need to keep those two event but handle the piority myself

Comment: You can change the functions though? Could you post an example of your inputs as well?